# Python/Django - Count of other objects using a certain object as a foreignkey

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am working on a test Django app, CatDB. I was each "owner" class to have a variable that is the number of cats listing that owner as their owner.

In my Models.py:
from django.db import models

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def num_cats(self): //This is the line in question
        return cat_set.count()

class Cat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I tried to accomplish this with a variable called num_cats but it isnt working.

Also, in my Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from catdb.models import Cat, Owner


class OwnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Basic information', {'fields': ['name','location'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('name','location','num_cats') //Use num_cats as a column in the list


admin.site.register(Owner, OwnerAdmin)
admin.site.register(Cat)
```

How can I implement this properly?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `cat_set.count()` you need `self.cat_set.count()` so it should be:

```
def num_cats(self):
    return self.cat_set.count()
```